Date doesn’t change in between different views
I am building myself simple app showing different movies fetched from GraphQL server. I am trying to convert date as a String I get from GraphQL into Date object that I can later reformat. I handle this conversion into Date object in custom written init of my view with a simple code like this
init(film: FetchFilmsQuery.Data.AllFilms.Film) {
        self.film = film

        let inputDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        inputDateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        if let releaseDate = film.releaseDate {
            if let date = inputDateFormatter.date(from: releaseDate) {
                self._releaseDate = State(initialValue: date)
            }
        }
    }

I have multiple of these film views, but no matter what, the date property stays the same among all of those. It always shows the same date everywhere based on what film I selected first.
If anyone is interested, full code can be seen here
https://github.com/StepanPazderka/StarWarsApp

can you update your question with minimal reproducible code ? Include code that shows the date in different views, how date is passed, and how your model is stored etc.

Yes, there are different Dates being loaded into the state, interestingly enough, it instantiates all views twice. At least the print statement is being invoked twice. But in UI I only see first date that is display and that then stays the same on all other views.

You need to provide more context. What object is that who's init method you provided? How is it created? What's its lifecycle? (yes, we could download the full app, but that's more than I have time for.)

You could try using .onAppear {...} instead of init.
For example:
struct MovieDetailView: View {
    let film: FetchFilmsQuery.Data.AllFilms.Film
    @State private var releaseDate: Date?
    
    var body: some View {
        // view code
        .onAppear {
            if let date = film.releaseDate {
                let inputDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                inputDateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
                releaseDate = inputDateFormatter.date(from: date)
            }
        }
    }
}


did my answer not worked for you?
